# objectiveC protocol issue Detail -> Master communication

Tags: ios, ipad, xcode4.2, xcode4.3, master-detail

I am using a UISplitViewController to manage the Master and Detail view. Everything is working fine going from master to detail. I can select an item from the list and through the delegate it updates the detail view.

I want to be able to delete an item using a button on the detail view. This is very simple to do on the detail view. However, I cannot seem to figure out how to change the master view to reflect the fact that an item has been deleted.

Here is my example: [SampleCode](http://www.file-upload.net/download-4294356/Simple_SplitView_Controller_Example.zip.html)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Make the master a delegate of the detail view. That is: when you fire up the detail from the master, tell the detail who the master is, preferably by using a delegate construction.That way the detail can inform the master when any changes should occur.

Or you can also put the data in CoreData, and have the master notified automatically when a changes occurs in the CoreData tables. Check `NSManagedObjectContextObjectsDidChangeNotification` for more info.

Comment: how can I use the delegate construction, do you have an example?

Comment: sure, this is quite a nice example:  http://www.roostersoftstudios.com/2011/04/12/simple-delegate-tutorial-for-ios-development/

Comment: as you can see in my example I use exactly the same delegate structure, unfortunately it doesn't work, the entries will be not deleted from the array. That is the reason why I asked the question.