# Master/Detail Application : Add a second Split View Controller to the Detail View

Tags: xcode4.3, uisplitviewcontroller, master-detail

I have a MAster/Detail Application and everything is fine.
 Now when loaded, we have the Button Named "Master" That will slide over the original Master View Controller.
 I want to change it's behavior ,so instead of popping over the original MasterViewController..
i need it to popOver another SplitViewController with the option of going back to the original one.
 Any ideas how to create this? I dunno where to start.
 Any ideas will be highly appreciated

**Please Check This Edit** 
Edit 1 : 
To be more precise...i have a dictionary application that first loads all the elements in the master view controller on the left...once i click on any element, it will open up in details view controller as it should.
Once in the Details view controller..if i click on Add to Favorites button...and click on the button Show Favorites...i need it to show me in the MasterViewControlle all the selected favorites instead of all the dictionary elements...how can i do it?

Comment: For this you can create a customized splitViewcontroller of your own.. as it is not possible to have 2 default split view controllers in the same application.

Answer (score 1):

Seeing your question i feel you want to have UISplitViewController like below.

[image]

I never worked on it but try out this tutorial and try to integrate this feature in your project.

Raywenderlich tutorial link [Click here](http://www.raywenderlich.com/1040/ipad-for-iphone-developers-101-uisplitview-tutorial)

UISplitViewController class reference [Click here](http://developer.apple.com/library/ios/#documentation/uikit/reference/UISplitViewController_class/Reference/Reference.html)

Answer (score 0):

check [this Question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/10463394/objectivec-protocol-issue-detail-master-communication) already asked in stackoverflow  if you want to use protocol [objectiveC protocol issue Detail -> Master communication](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/10463394/objectivec-protocol-issue-detail-master-communication).

You can use KVO as well.Check [this Link](http://2pi.dk/tech/cocoa/kvo_dispatch.html) : http://2pi.dk/tech/cocoa/kvo_dispatch.html